# Array of non-type template?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I have a non-type template class Foo:

```
template <int n>
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(){}
};
```

How can I store multiple instances of that class in one array? (When the instances all have different template values.)

This, however, does not work:

```
Foo<int> myArray[] = {Foo<1>() , Foo<2>() , Foo<3>()};
```

Compiler error is: *template argument for non-type template parameter must be
      an expression*

Comment: You can't. They are all different types. A class template is not a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Foo<1>` is not the same type as `Foo<2>` (and so on),
so you can't store them in a array (if they derived from `FooBase`, you may have an array of `FooBase*`).

You may store them in a `std::tuple`:

```
auto foos = std::make_tuple(Foo<1>() , Foo<2>() , Foo<3>());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template <int n>
class Foo : public Ifoo {
public:
  Foo(){}
};

IFoo* myArray[] = {..
```

Comment: That is not storing instances of a class, it is storing pointers.

Comment: Did you mean `Ifoo * myArray[] = { ...`?

Answer (score 1):

As had been mentioned, `Foo<1>` is a different type to `Foo<2>` etc etc, so you can't store them in an array.

To get around this you can de-template the class and make the integer a constructor argument instead:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo(int n){}
};

Foo myArray[] = {Foo(1) , Foo(2) , Foo(3)};
```